# Error while building Docker: "Package 'mongodb' has no installation csndidate" with python:3.7 image

Tags: python, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to build this docker image with docker compose:

```
FROM python:3.7-slim

# Keeps Python from generating .pyc files in the container
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE=1

# Turns off buffering for easier container logging
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    make \
    gcc \
    python3-dev \
    mongodb



# Create working directory and copy all files
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

# Pip install requirements
RUN pip install --user -r requirements.txt

# Port to expose
EXPOSE 8000
# During debugging, this entry point will be overridden. For more information, please refer to https://aka.ms/vscode-docker-python-debug
CMD ["python", "main.py", "runserver"]
```

but i get this error:

```
Package 'mongodb' has no installation candidate
```

When I run the same exact docker image with `python:3.4-slim` it works. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `python:3.4-slim` uses Debian stretch (9) for its base and the `mongodb` package is available in its repos. But for `python:3.7-slim`, the base is bullseye (11) and mongodb is no longer in its repos.

I'd recommend not to install mongodb in the image that you're building above but rather use a separate mongodb container.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I used a different image anyway cause, well its the point of containerization, but I was trying to undertand why it was failing